# How to integrate Amazon Alexa SDK to the android app?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Can any one please let me know about how to integrate Alexa AVS SDK to the android app.I have been searching seens long but not getting actual documentation about how this will work with custom mobile app for android.

i want feature like ultimate alexa app which is there in google play store.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create Amazon developer account. 
  Then create the security profile and add Product.
  [This link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/amazon-alexa-voice-library-replacing-android-home-will-blaschko-ma) will help you to get started.

You can find a sample application [here](https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid)

This command help you to get MD5 and SHA256 keys from terminal or window

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Thanks Jessica!!..let me check.